# drools rule compilation error only a type can be imported. resolves to a package

Tags: java, drools, kie

I'm using **kie-maven-plugin** to compile all the rules to a **KJAR**.

After I run the maven command **mvn clean install -DgenerateModel=YES**, there are some compiler error like this:

```
[WARNING] ClassNotFoundException occured!
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to find class 'com.rules.engine.service.RuleValidationErrorServiceImpl'
```

and

```
Error importing : 'com.model.rules.CodeRule'
Rule Compilation error : [Rule name='1.1.a']
    com/rule2/Rule_1$u46$1$u46$a2059806722.java (2:38) : Only a type can be imported. com.model.rules.CodeRule resolves to a package
    com/rule2/Rule_1$u46$1$u46$a2059806722.java (7:417) : $responseCodeRule cannot be resolved
    com/rule2/Rule_1$u46$1$u46$a2059806722.java (7:444) : ruleValidationErrorService cannot be resolved
    com/rule2/Rule_1$u46$1$u46$a2059806722.java (8:487) : $responseCodeRule cannot be resolved
```

But strangely, the build is successful even with those compile errors. There is a jar created with all those rules compiled into classes.

I have done a lot of searches but still couldn't figure it out. Anyone who might have such experience please helps me to resolve those compile errors. Super thanks!

Comment: I get this when the path to the class is incorrect

Answer (score -1):

This definitely looks like a bug in the executable model compiler compilation, can you check if the .class files of Rule_1$u46$1$u46$a2059806722.java are generated in the KJAR?

You can use `jar tf kiejarname.jar` too see the files

In the meanwhile, can you provide us a reproducer for these rules?

Thank you very much

Comment: .class files of Rule_1$u46$1$u46$a2059806722.java are not generated.
But I do see those are generated, which couldn't be resolved in Rule Compilation error.
DomainClassesMetadata54A9BC2A041F7030E8612ADC37BDA020$com_model_rules_ResponseCodeRule_Metadata.class
DomainClassesMetadata5CF524AE74C12EA1CEED7DD3C4DB042E$com_rules_engine_service_RuleValidationErrorServiceImpl_Metadata.class.

will write an example code and share here later.